# UWP: App Top Bar always shows on right click, how to prevent it?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, appbar

I have an application that is already on the Windows 10 Store. It has an AppBar with items, such as File, Edit, Help.

When I right click on any control inside the app, say ListView, the AppBar shows up. Why?

I want to create context menu for ListView, but the context menu isn't showing up, because AppBar becomes focused? How can I prevent this?

**Note**: if I comment out AppBar in xaml, everything is working as expected.

Comment: Can you show your codes

Comment: Are you created appbar inside of grid or using page.appbar

Comment: It's just a single Page: in xaml Page -> Page.TopAppBar -> AppBar. Page has a single Grid, after Page.TopAppBar.

Comment: You can hide it in listview focus event

Comment: Try moving the `AppBar` from the `Page.TopAppBar` to the `Grid` or changing it to `CommandBar` which is really similar to the `AppBar` control.

Comment: Thanks @MarianDolinský, converting it to CommandBar did the job! Please post your comment as an answer, and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `AppBar` to `CommandBar` which is really similar and recommended in UWP.

> XAML provides both the AppBar control and the CommandBar control. You should use the AppBar only when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses the AppBar, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the CommandBar control instead.
>   ([Command bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars))